# POSIX Multi-thread handling C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, posix

So, this is homework. I'm looking for more guidance than given code but I wouldn't argue for a bit of more direct assistance..

The homework is to have 20 threads of one-way bound "trains" to a City of Fairhope and Mobile, 10 each. (they're local cities..)

Anyhow.. I've tried a lot of ways and went through a lot of searches here in stack but I cannot find one that's like mine. Most are just threads that suppose to cooperate. In this case, my mutex is the "tunnel" that the trains are travelling through. If I have a train headed to mobile, other trains headed to mobile can use it aswell. Same applies for fairhope. They have to be randomly generated at each iteration. I think this is closest I've gotten to code that may make sense.. What's wrong with this stuff? :\

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    using namespace std;
    // data types, num_mobile/fairhope to keep track of how many threads
    // created in their name, num_tunnel to see which way its going [-1,0,1]
    // tunnel_state is for the mutex
    int num_tunnel = 0,
    num_mobile = 0,
    num_fairhope = 0,
    tunnel_state = -1;

    pthread_mutex_t train_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t train_cont = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    int n_sleep(unsigned long);
    int pick_train();

    int n_sleep(unsigned long milisec) {
        struct timespec req={0};
        time_t sec=(int)(milisec/1000);
        milisec=milisec-(sec*1000);
        req.tv_sec=sec;
        req.tv_nsec=milisec*1000000L;
        while(nanosleep(&req,&req)==-1)
            continue;
        return 1;
        }

    int pick_train() {
        int randNum = rand() % 10 + 1;
        return randNum;
    }

    // posix threads to lock, broadcast and manipulate thread in a loop to keep track of train position. based on fairhope/mobile bound thread in main
    void *deploy_mobile(void *tid) {
        int id = (long int)tid;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&train_mutex);
        while (tunnel_state != 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&train_cont, &train_mutex);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                cout << "Mobile-bound #" << id << " has entered the tunnel" << endl;
                num_tunnel += 1;
            } else if (i == 9) {
                cout << "Mobile-bound #" << id << " has exited the tunnel" << endl;
                num_tunnel = num_tunnel - 1;
            }
            n_sleep(1000);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&train_mutex);
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&train_cont);
        }
    }

    void *deploy_fairhope(void *tid) {
        int id = (long int)tid;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&train_mutex);
        while (tunnel_state != 1) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&train_cont, &train_mutex);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                cout << "Fairhope-bound #" << id << " has entered the tunnel" << endl;
                num_tunnel += 1;
            } else if (i == 9) {
                cout << "Fairhope-bound #" << id << " has exited the tunnel" << endl;
                num_tunnel = num_tunnel - 1;
            }
            n_sleep(1000);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&train_mutex);
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&train_cont);
        }
    }

    // main, creates 10 of each thread, loop randomly generates which way train is going up to a max of 10 each. iterations on num_mobile/fairhope.
    int main(void) {
        pthread_t train_mob[10];
        pthread_t train_fair[10];
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (long int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            if ( (pick_train() < 5) && (num_mobile != 10) ) {
                if (tunnel_state == -1) {
                    tunnel_state = 0;
                }
                pthread_create(&train_mob[num_mobile], NULL, deploy_mobile, (void *)i);
                num_mobile += 1;
            } else if ( (pick_train() < 5) && (num_mobile == 10) && (num_fairhope != 10) ) {
                if (tunnel_state == -1) {
                    tunnel_state = 0;
                }
                pthread_create(&train_fair[num_fairhope], NULL, deploy_fairhope, (void *)i);
                num_fairhope += 1;
            } else if ( (pick_train() > 4) && (num_fairhope != 10) ) {
                if (tunnel_state == -1) {
                    tunnel_state = 1;
                }
                pthread_create(&train_fair[num_fairhope], NULL, deploy_fairhope, (void *)i);
                num_fairhope += 1;
            } else if ( (pick_train() > 4) && (num_fairhope == 10) && (num_mobile != 10) ) {
                if (tunnel_state == -1) {
                    tunnel_state = 0;
                }
                pthread_create(&train_mob[num_mobile], NULL, deploy_mobile, (void *)i);
                num_mobile += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I realized some of the libraries arent needed any longer. Leftovers from re-writes.

Expected outcome:
        Mobile-bound #1 wants to enter tunnel
        Mobile-bound #1 enters tunnel
        (sleep 1000, return to main to generate new train)
        Fairhope-bound #1 wants to enter tunnel
        (sleep 1000, return to main to generate new train)
        Mobile-bound #2 wants to enter tunnel
        Mobile-bound #2 enters tunnel
        (sleep 1000, return t0 main to generate new train)

Process repeats 10 times for each thread. At end of loop in thread function train exits. If all trains of a certain type exited and num_tunnel reaches 0 then it will allow for the other side to pass.

Current output: Nothing. Exits status 0

Comment: Please describe the output you're expecting and compare that to the output you're getting.

Comment: output I'm expecting
Mobile-bound train #0 wants to enter the tunnel
Mobile-bound train #0 enters the tunnel
(sleep 1000, return to generate new thread)
(random new train, fairhope)
Fairhope-bound train #0 wants to enter the tunnel
(sleep 1000, return to generate new thread)
(random new train, mobile)
Mobile-bound train #1 wants to enter the tunnel
Mobile-bound train #1 enters the tunnel

repeat however 10 loops. States Mobile bound trains leaving. All mobile-bound must leave before Fairhope-bound can enter tunnel. It could also, by random, mean Fairhope starts first.

Comment: I edited the main() code in the loop, incase you already read it.. I forgot to write nested if to ensure no more than 10 of each. also... I didnt know if I could have two different thread functions to handle them. I assumed it didnt matter and made the most sense to cut down on redundant code or loops on loops on loops... I couldnt find if it was OK or not but it didnt seem to have an issue... aaaand Im getting segmentation faults immediately on attempt to run this.

Comment: correction: since i finished the nested ifs in main it only prints out nothingness, no segmentation faults and no output

Comment: So you already know that your program is not a minimal example, but you still post that here, against the guidelines? Also, add the expected outcome to the question, it should be an integral part thereof! That said, you are not checking any calls for errors and your code is completely undocumented. In particular information about the data that should be protected by a mutex is important.

Comment: I dont know what a minimal example is. That's like 80 lines, if you dont count my code style (like blank lines between stuff). Sure, it's undocumented. It's a short-term homework assignment. Look if you dont want to help dont help, I dont really feel like being yelled at.

and yes I am sorry about not noting absolutely everything in the first post. It was an oversight but I'm working on this as I ask the question not asking and coming back later to find out if someone  told me how to do it all.

Comment: Okay Ulrich I have edited everything to include what was spoken of here.

Comment: The idea and rationale behind a minimal example is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Concerning the documentation, the point is that if you have no plan how to structure things, it's no surprise that things don't work the way you intend them to. That said, if you consider that "yelling", your problem. However, I see at least one of your faults and nudged you in the right direction. I could also tell you straight away, but that would spoil you a learning experience. Good luck!

Comment: I assume you mean I shouldnt be altered train_state inside the main when you said that. I'll start there, thank you